# Django: Dynamic LOGIN_URL variable

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Currently, in my `settings` module I have this:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
```

If I ever decide to change the login URL in `urls.py`, I'll have to change it here as well. Is there any more dynamic way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Settings *IS* where you are setting your dynamic login url. Make sure to import `LOGIN_URL` from `settings.py` in your `urls.py` and use that instead.

```
from projectname.settings import LOGIN_URL
```

Comment: But how do I fit that into `urlpatterns`? :/

Comment: from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from projectname.settings import LOGIN_URL

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/2003/' + LOGIN_URL + '/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),

Answer (score 4):

This works for me ... with LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'

**If the problem is** that settings.py has ...

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'  # <-- remember trailing slash!
```

... but, urls.py wants ...

```
url(r'^login/$', 
      auth_views.login, {'template_name': '/foo.html'}, 
            name='auth_login'),
```

**Then do this:**

```
# - up top in the urls.py
from django.conf import settings

# - down below, in the list of URLs ...
# - blindly remove the leading '/' & trust that you have a trailing '/'
url(r'^%s$' % settings.LOGIN_URL[1:], 
      auth_views.login, {'template_name': '/foo.html'}, 
            name='auth_login'),
```

If you can't trust whomever edits your settings.py
... then check LOGIN_URL startswith a slash & snip it off, or not.
... and then check for trailing slash LOGIN_URL endswith a slash &  tack it on, or not
... and and then tack on the '$'